# Sidebar Categories change arrow when subcategories are shown on click

Tags: categories, sidebar

I have an arrow on the maincategory if a particular category has subcategory, iam using jquery animation to slideup, slidedown subcategory. i want to remove previous arrow and replace it with different arrow when the subcategories slidesdown

Here is my Jquery code for Reference:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("aside ul li:has(ul)").addClass("ic-arrdn");
    var e = $("aside > ul > li.current-cat, aside > ul > li.current-cat-parent");
    if (e.length == 1) {
    }
    $("aside > ul > li > ul.children").each(function () {
        $(this).find("li")
        $(this).parent().toggle(function () {
            $(this).find("ul").slideDown()
        }, function () {
            $(this).find("ul").slideUp()
        })
    })
});
```

This the markup:

```
-<ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6797 ic-arrdn"><a href="http://johndoe.com/cat1">Cat 2</a><span>(234)</span>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-7492"><a href="http://johndoe.com/cat1-sub" title="View all posts filed under cat1">Cat 1</a><span>(1)</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I Add the Class ic-arrdn if there are subcategories in the category, then if the main category is clicked i want the class to change from ic-arrdn to ic-arrup..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these lines:
$(this).removeClass('ic-arrdn').addClass('ic-arrup');
$(this).removeClass('ic-arrdn').addClass('ic-arrup');

and achieved the result.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("aside ul li:has(ul)").addClass("ic-arrdn");
        var e = $("aside > ul > li.current-cat, aside > ul > li.current-cat-parent");
        if (e.length == 1) {
        }
        $("aside > ul > li > ul.children").each(function () {
            $(this).find("li")
            $(this).parent().toggle(function () {
                $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
                $(this).removeClass('ic-arrdn').addClass('ic-arrup');   
            }, function () {
                $(this).find("ul").slideUp();
                $(this).removeClass('ic-arrdn').addClass('ic-arrup');   
            });
        });
    });
```